# How to run a script on Azure VM from a remote machine

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services, dsc

I'm looking for a way to run a script, on a single instance of a cloud service (which has several instances) from a remote machine.

I've tried DSC but that doesn't seem to support running the script only on one machine, as it would run it on all machines of the cloud service.

Note I'm using classic Azure cloud services.

Update: I specifically have an issue with Get-AzureVM which is part of the script example. 
How do I get the instance VM which is part of my cloud service. 
For instance I tried:

```
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName myCloudServiceName -Name instanceVMName
```

And that didn't return anything (I made sure to Add-AzureAccount first).

I’m assuming it returns nothing because Get-AzureVM cannot be used for cloud services, and only for VMs.
I’m able to get the instance by running
$dep = Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName myCloudServiceName -Slot Production 
$dep.RoleInstanceList[0] 
Which returns role instance type which is different from the expected VM type.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[Powershell Remoting in Azure Cloud Services](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mariok/2011/08/08/command-line-access-to-azure-vms-powershell-remoting/)

As you are using a single instance the above should do the trick, you will need to create the user as part of a startup script, otherwise it will disappear each time it recreates the VM.  It will not work if you every scale out to more than one instance of a cloud service.

Comment: I actually have several instances as part of my cloud service and would like to run a script only of one of them. I will also update the question with this information

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Custom Script extension for Windows virtual machines**. **It supports run on a single VM.**

With the Custom Script extension for Windows, you can run PowerShell scripts on a remote VM without signing in to it. You can run the scripts after provisioning the VM, or at any time during the lifecycle of the VM without opening any additional ports. The most common use cases for running Custom Script extension include running, installing, and configuring additional software on the VM after it's provisioned.

More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-classic-extensions-customscript).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I specifically have an issue with Get-AzureVM command which is part of the script. How do I get the VM instance which is part of my cloud service? 
I tried using Get-AzureVM with the cloud service name and the instance name and unfortunatelly that didn't return anything.

Comment: I had the same, but was due to multiple subscriptions.  You can check with get-AzureSubscription

Comment: I made sure to run Add-AzureAccount first, and set a default subscription (also updated the question description) but still cannot get a result when running Get-AzureVM. 
I would guess that Get-AzureVM cannot be used for cloud services and only for Azure VMs? 
If so, how can I use it?

Comment: https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2015/08/14/azure-automation-remote-powershell-and-a-virtual-machine/  That is working, but I think you can only restart the service, delete etc.  The link attached may help as that will work with a cloud service too and you can interact on the VM.

Comment: @RavitD `I would guess that Get-AzureVM cannot be used for cloud services and only for Azure VMs?` No, you could use `Get-AzureVM` to get Azure VM. Do you check your install is right? According to your scenario, I test in my lab, I could get the VM's list.

Comment: @RavitD Do you try to use `Get-AzureVM`. If you could get your VM's information, I think you could check your VM's instance name.

Comment: When typing Get-AzureVM I get a list of VMs on my subscription but nothing that includes my Azure cloud services. 
Please see my updated question, I'm able to get the instances by running Get-AzureDeployment which returnst he list of instances as roles.

Comment: @RavitD Yes, I know your instances existed. I suggest you use `Get-AzureVM`  without any parameter. According to your description, I think your subscription which you select is right.

Comment: @SteveNewton in your link seems you are also using Get-AzureVM command which for me returns nothing so I have the same issue there. Any idea whytha tcommand returns nothing?

Comment: @Walter-MSFT as noted, when using Get-AzureVM without any parameters I get the list of VMs on my subscription but my cloud services are not listed there, nor are the VM instances which are part of my cloud service.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133247/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-ravit-d).